# Unity (Javascript Syntax) Isn't Allowing Me to Override My Inherited Method

Tags: unity

First, I would like to say I apologize if this has already been asked and there is already an available thread covering this. I did my very best to try and find a resolution to this using preexisting resources, but nothing is really helping me.

Next the information I've been working from is here:

http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Head_First_into_Unity_with_UnityScript#Virtual_functions_can_be_used_to_override_functions

It states that the virtual keyword is used to override functions/methods down the line if inherited from another object. More so it is my understanding that Unity automatically uses virtual key word unless otherwise specified.

So hypothetically with this train of thought in mind I would simply just pre-pend override in my function declaration and it should override it. However. That is not the case.

What occurs next is an error:

> Assets/Scripts/Classes/Actors/TestPlayer.js(500,18): BCE0089: Type 'TestActor' already has a definition for 'getMovementVector()'.

Below are the class definitions shortened to just the initial skeleton and the functions I'm discussing.

```
class Actor extends DefaultGameObject {
    function getMovementVector() : Vector3 {
        var moveDirection = Vector3(0, 0, 0);

        if(isJumping && !jumpUsed) {

            //TODO: If double jump is added modify this line
            //so that the speed can be changed if you want that
            moveDirection.y += jumpSpeed;

            if(jumpTimer < jumpTimerMax) {
                jumpTimer++;
            }
            else {
                isJumping = false;
                jumpUsed = true;
                //animatedImage.animateOnceAndStopAtEnd(39, 39, 41);
            }
        }

        if((movingLeft || movingRight) && !(movingLeft && movingRight)) {
            if(movingLeft) {
                moveDirection.x -= moveSpeed;
            }
            if(movingRight) {
                moveDirection.x += moveSpeed;
            }
        }

        //applies gravity
        if(!isJumping) {
            moveDirection.y -= fallSpeed;
        }

        return moveDirection;
    }
}
```

Below is the code for the class that inherits from the above class with its function/method.

```
class TestActor extends Actor {
    override function getMovementVector() : Vector3 {
        var moveDirection = Vector3(0, 0, 0);

        if(isJumping && !jumpUsed) {
            if(doubleJumpUsed) {
                moveDirection.y += jumpSpeed;
            }
            else {
                //Debug.Log("omg jumping");
                moveDirection.y += jumpSpeed;
            }
            if(jumpTimer < jumpTimerMax) {
                jumpTimer++;
            }
            else {
                isJumping = false;
                jumpUsed = true;
                animatedImage.animateOnceAndStopAtEnd(39, 39, 41);
            }
        }

        if((movingLeft || movingRight) && !(movingLeft && movingRight)) {
            if(movingLeft) {
                moveDirection.x -= moveSpeed;
            }
            if(movingRight) {
                moveDirection.x += moveSpeed;
            }
        }

        //applies gravity
        if(!isJumping) {
            moveDirection.y -= fallSpeed;
        }
        return moveDirection;
    }
}
```

To me it seems relatively straightforward, but no matter what I do I cannot for the life of me get it to stop complaining about a method that has already been declared for it. I've tried explicitly using the virtual keyword as well. I tried adding access modifiers and that didn't change anything.

I would really appreciate any help or directions on where I can go for this. Thank you.

Comment: Why not mark both to be virtual like in the example?

Comment: I have tried that and it doesn't rectify it either. Also, I stated above that Unity implicitly adds the virtual keyword to variable declarations, so the implication is that they should both already have access modifiers of virtual with or without me explicitly adding it in. I also stated that above.

Comment: In Actor - virtual and in TestActor - override?

Comment: Have you asked at the Unity Answers site? This question isn't off-topic here but the syntax is Unity-specific and there will be more people familiar with the issue there. (I would suggest dropping the override term, as it doesn't appear to exist in the docs there.)

Comment: `class Actor extends DefaultGameObject {` That's JavaScript?

Comment: It's not really JavaScript - it's actually called UnityScript. It's something that could be considered to be Unity's adaptation of JavaScript. Although I'm doing all of my gamedev under Unity at the moment, I have very little experience with UnityScript, and I stay away from it. As Kylotan also said, asking the Unity Answers site might be a better idea.

Comment: Hrm. Perhaps you both are correct in that I should relocate this question. Regarding the syntax Bogdan is correct in that this is the Javascript syntax which should be more aptly renamed UnityScript so that the misnomer no longer contributes to these types of clarifications. Thank you very much for your input guys. I have tried all the variations I can think of regarding override, virtual, and nothing works. If someone else viewing this thread knows the issue I would appreciate any help. I will also post this on the Unity Answers site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh wow... This is embarrassing...

I'm just a big dope and didn't realize hidden in my file there was an empty method by the same name declared.

Thank you to all those who tried to answer this question. I appreciate the time and patience you all demonstrated.

Comment: Remember to accept your own answer so that this question register as properly solved.

Answer (score 0):

UnityScript doesn't use the override keyword. Use virtual instead.

http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Head_First_into_Unity_with_UnityScript#Virtual_functions_can_be_used_to_override_functions

Edit: Looking your question over again, it seems you've already tried that. Are you sure you did it the way it shows at the link? I'm not sure why your code isn't complaining about the use of "override"; it's not even a keyword in UnityScript.

Comment: Yes, I am trying this in the same way that this is shown to me in the link.